# PHP: array_push() not working in my pcntl_fork() structure

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, bash, shell

I'm developing multithread script for wordpress system using `pcntl`(http://php.net/manual/ro/book.pcntl.php) for generate child process that work in parallel.

When I created child process i need to return process ID for check it in a second moment, but in my foreach structure `array_push()` not working.

For testing `pcntl` and `fork` i've used this example https://gist.github.com/nicksantamaria/21dce5ff2a6640cdff76ce7bc57d2981

my function:

```
$tasks = [
  "fetch_remote_data",
  "post_async_updates",
  "clear_caches",
  "notify_admin",
];

$child_pid = [];
$i = 0;

echo "PARENT PROCESS ID => " . getmypid() . PHP_EOL;

foreach ($tasks as $task) {
  $pid = pcntl_fork();

  if ($pid == -1) {
    exit("Error forking...\n");
  }
  elseif ($pid == 0) {
    $my_pid = getmypid();

    array_push($child_pid , $my_pid);
    echo 'PARTIAL CHILD IDS ARRAY' . PHP_EOL;
    print_r($child_pid);

    echo "My task '$task' ID is $my_pid \r\n";
    echo "Starting task: ${task}\n";

    //return_child_process_id($my_pid, $i);
    execute_task($task, $i);

    exit();
  }
  $i++;
}

while(pcntl_waitpid(0, $status) != -1);

echo "Do stuff after all parallel execution is complete.\n";
print_r($child_pid);
echo 'Child Id: ' . PHP_EOL; 

function execute_task($task_id, $i) {
  echo "Starting task: ${task_id}\n";

  $execution_time = rand(5, 10);
  sleep($execution_time);

  $return = pcntl_get_last_error();  

  echo "Completed task: ${task_id}. Key ID  IS $i , with the error: ". $return ." => " .  pcntl_strerror($return) . PHP_EOL;
}
```

but my return into shell..

[image]

Why my `array_push()` not working and my `$child_pid` remain empty?

---

**UPDATE**

I've solved my problem using external file for save my proces ID:

```
  $fp = fopen('data.txt', 'a');
  fwrite($fp, $mypid . PHP_EOL);
  fclose($fp);
```

Comment: Well... your `print_r($child_pid);` at the end can't ever display anything since every time you're using `array_push`, you're exiting the script right after.

Comment: @Jeto if I don't exit from my script, my child process is not killed, as if I put the exit in the end of the foreach

Comment: Or if I not exit from foreach... array is empty

Comment: Whene i move `exit()` in different position generate infinite childs-process whene I have to kill manually